# Get same left shift value in Java as Python

Tags: java, bit-shift

Specifically I want to take this number:

x = 1452610545672622396

and perform

x ^= (x << 21)  // In Python I do x ^= (x << 21) & 0xffffffffffffffff

and get: 12043412836254060860     // Which is what I get in Python

instead of: -6403331237455490756  // Which is what I get in Java (and don't want)

Comment: What type do you use to store that number in Java, what is `x`?

Comment: Sorry, it's a long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store x as a `BigInteger` and call `shiftLeft` on it, then do your xor operation.

Why: You need 61 bits to represent 1452610545672622396, and shifting it left 21 will overflow a long (64 bits).

--

You cannot convert the result back to a long, because it needs 64 bits and you can only use 63 of those + sign.
(log2 12043412836254060860 = 63.3848780807)

Here's sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long x = 1452610545672622396L;

    BigInteger bigX = BigInteger.valueOf(x);
    bigX = bigX.shiftLeft(21).xor(bigX).and(new BigInteger("ffffffffffffffff", 16));

    System.out.println(bigX); // 12043412836254060860
    System.out.println(bigX.longValue()); // -6403331237455490756
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? Did you get the same result as the OP expects?

Comment: Yes, just updated the answer. @JornVernee's reply is also valid.

Comment: So I guess If I have a number that big I can't really work with it? What I really need is this random number generator to work in both Python and Java: https://gist.github.com/cogmission/c4cb8feaba19595dae8ff964e18b05d0

The problem is, when the seed gets to be the above number, the Java version goes negative... So I guess I need to test for a certain size and do something to both when the size gets to be a certain number so that it never over flows Java?

Comment: You will need to use BigInteger or similar (BigDecimal for floats) in order to prevent overflows. BigInteger contains an integer array that it uses to act like a high-bit number.

Comment: @learner0000 Thank you very much for your work and your guidance on this.

Comment: @learner0000 Hey can you guys answer the reverse?  I figured I'd give you guys a shot first?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872627/get-the-same-shift-left-in-python-as-java