# Get the same shift left in Python as Java

Tags: java, python, bit-shift

Specifically I want to take this number:

```
x = 1452610545672622396
```

and perform

```
x ^= (x << 21) // In Python I do x ^= (x << 21) & 0xffffffffffffffff
```

**I want to get:** `-6403331237455490756`, which is what I get in Java

instead of: `12043412836254060860`, which is what I get in Python (**which is what I don't want**)

EDIT: In Java I do:

```
long x = 1452610545672622396;
x ^= (x << 21);
```

Comment: @sun qingyao Thanks, that's a lot more clear... +1

Comment: You're welcome. I've just formatted the code, and you can make it even clearer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 64bit signed int like java using [ctypes.c_longlong](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c%5Flonglong), please see example below:

```
from ctypes import c_longlong as ll

x = 1452610545672622396

output = ll(x^(x<<21))

print output
print output.__class__
```

Comment: Hi Thanks! What's the best way to get the value back out (not as a string) but as a long I can work with?

Comment: @cogmission I've edited my answer to make it more clear to you, as you can see the __class__ of output will be <class 'ctypes.c_longlong'> , which is what you want to use

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really a Python programmer so I just used ```ll().value``` - but I wanted to see if there was a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You might cause an overflow. Java long is 64 bit long while python has no size limit. Try using Long wrapper class of long. The Long object has also no limits (Well technicially everything has its limits...).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I want to do is normalize the Python, not the Java - so in fact "force" the overflow in Python?